# How to create duplicate Wordpress post content using wpdb query?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress

I've created a demo website where I want every post to have the same content. I've created 50 posts through a random post generator plugin. I have edited one post's content. Now is there a way to copy the content and paste to all 49 other posts?

E.g. I used this query to duplicate the excerpt.

```
$wpdb->query( "UPDATE wp_posts SET post_excerpt='This is an excerpt for the post' " );
```

Looking for a similar query. Please guide.

Comment: @tadman New to WP, even then I know that it's not going to be `INSERT`. Instead it can be `UPDATE` since the other 49 posts already have random content in them. Can you elaborate?

Comment: If you create one post you want to clone you can do `INSERT INTO ... SELECT FROM` to copy it. Otherwise you'll need to do a self-join `UPDATE` clause, which is a lot messier.

Comment: It's not that easy I'm afraid... especially if you have attachments or plugins that have created custom meta fields. It might be a bit late, but the easiest way to do this is using a plugin - [Duplicate Post](https://wordpress.org/plugins/duplicate-post/) is one of the most popular. If the ids of the posts you already created don't matter, then it might be worth using it anyway. If not, it is possible to do it through PHP using WP functions so you're not messing around in the database directly. Let me know if you really need to do that and I'll see if I can dig out my old code.